# Reload UITableView that is inside UIViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm learning swift and today I got a problem. I'm creating an app that displays movie theaters and their schedules. Something like this:

[image]

The idea is there are 3 buttons which will show a theater's schedule for today, the next day and the day after that ( I don't know the right word, sorry :( ) if clicked. For example, the first button shows today's schedule:

[image]

First time the view is load, it always shows today's schedule. But the other buttons don't work and I don't know why.

I got tableView's delegate and datasource in `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method.

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Delegate/datasource for tableView that shows theater's schedule
    showtimeTable.delegate = self
    showtimeTable.dataSource = self
    showtimeTable.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Here is the action func. Because 3 buttons has the same purpose so I connected them all to 1 func, I tested and they worked fine with the "get button text" method.

[image]

```
@IBAction func isClickedDate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    selectedDay = Int(sender.titleLabel!.text!)!
}
```

After the day is selected, the app will go throw all the rooms of selected theater and all the shows in each room and pick every show that has the same day as selectedDay, store them in a list and return to a global variable showOnDate: [Show]

```
extension ShowtimeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

// MARK: Showtime tableView lifecycle and settings

// Set number of section based on number of show performed on selected day
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return showOnDate.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "showtimeCell", for: indexPath) as! ShowtimeTableViewCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = cell as! ShowtimeTableViewCell
    let dateTimeComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(dateComponents, from: showOnDate[indexPath.section].sDate)

    // Set cell image and labels based on shows of selected theater
    cell.showImage.image = showOnDate[indexPath.section].sFilm.fPoster
    cell.showName.text = "\(showOnDate[indexPath.section].sFilm.fName) (\(showOnDate[indexPath.section].sFilm.fYear))"
    cell.showTime.text = "\(dateTimeComponents.hour!):\(dateTimeComponents.minute!)"
}

// Get shows will be performed on selected date
func getShowList(date: Int) -> [Show] {
    var listShow = [Show]()
    for room in selectedTheater!.tRooms {
        for show in room.rShow {
            let dateTimeComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(dateComponents, from: show.sDate)
            if date == dateTimeComponents.day! {
                listShow += [show]
            }
        }
    }
    return listShow
}
```

}

I tried to include `showtimeTable.reloadData()` in the action func but nothing happened. Tried `DispatchQueue.main.async`, `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`, nothing worked ( I tried everything I know so maybe it didn't even have any impact ). Now I'm crying and I need help. Thanks a lot! ( I don't have enough reputation to embed image, sorry :( )

Comment: But you have enough reputation to post code as text rather than an image 

Comment: @vadian I thought an image will be easier to understand... Edited!

Comment: Could you please post the code how you set the data that is used in the TableView? Right now you are only changing the selectedDay variable but it is unclear what you are doing with that variable to me.

Comment: @hell2809 your button action is working but data is not reloading. is that your issue???

Comment: please Show Cell for row at index too

Comment: @TobiasGrunwald check my edit!

Comment: @Shezad yes it is

Comment: @AvinashMishra check my edit!

Comment: I found my way to resolve this issue in vadian's answer below. Turn out my knowledge is the problem. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the button action you need to update the `showOneDate` array with the shows related to `selectedDay` (like in `viewDidLoad`) and then reload the table view

```
@IBAction func isClickedDate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    selectedDay = Int(sender.titleLabel!.text!)!
    showOnDate = getShowList(date: selectedDay)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The reason to post (more) code as text is that the people who are willing to help are not necessarily willing to retype all the code

---

A suggestion:

Rather than getting the integer from the `titleLabel` I'd assign appropriate tags to the buttons, then you can simply write `selectedDay = sender.tag`

Comment: OMG! Worked like a champ!! You are my savior! But I'm wondering why `showOnDate = getShowList(date: selectedDay)` line in viewDidLoad doesn't work :(

Thank you, sir!

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` you have to add `tableView.reloadData()`, too. It's necessary every time after the data source array has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The action linked to the button is doing nothing, except changing the value of `selectedDay` variable.

So, my question is: in which manner are you retrieving the elements you are going to display in the table view? i.e. Can you show the implementation for your data source methods?

Here you can have different ways to achieve it. A simple one is to assign to `showOnDate` variable, a new list based on that selection and, after that, trigger `reloadData` method. **You don't need to perform any dispatch to main if you are already running on the main thread.**

Sample:

```
@IBAction func isClickedDate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    selectedDay = Int(sender.titleLabel!.text!)!
    showOnDate = getShowList(selectedDay)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Note:**

I would avoid to use this code

```
Int(sender.titleLabel!.text!)!
```

since is quite ugly. Maybe (just for learning new things) you can use the `tag` property for achieving this. The code will become more clean.

```
button.tag = 22
button2.tag = 23
// etc
```

and

```
@IBAction func isClickedDate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showOnDate = getShowList(sender.tag)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks for your support and the advice. I'm still new to this so little advice like yours is very helpful for me. Thanks again!